# Symfony 3.3 CraueFormFlowBundle Request_stack is empty

Tags: symfony-3.3

my first question to this site is a little difficult to describe.
I am quite new to Symfony, startet with 3.2 and updated recently to 3.3.5 (not sure if relevant for the problem).
I tried to use CraueFormFlowBundle (multistep form bundle) but cannot get it to work.
The problem is that trying to access the flow results in an exception:

```
Error: Call to a member function getCurrentRequest() on null

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ FatalErrorException
in vendor/craue/formflow-bundle/Form/FormFlow.php (line 191)
```

Line 191 shows:         $currentRequest = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

Modifying the FormFlow.php with dump line shows that $this->requestStack is null.
I have not enough knowledge about this bundle to know where to start looking for the problem.

The flow definition is based on the location example:

```
namespace EngineeringBundle\Form;

use Craue\FormFlowBundle\Form\FormFlow;
use Craue\FormFlowBundle\Form\FormFlowInterface;

class SelectExaminationFlow extends FormFlow
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function loadStepsConfig()
    {
        dump("loadStepsConfig");
        return array(
            array(
                'label' => 'engineering.discipline',
                'form_type' => new SelectExaminationStep1Form(),
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'engineering.date',
                'form_type' => new SelectExaminationStep2Form(),
                        'skip' => function($estimatedCurrentStepNumber, FormFlowInterface $flow) {
                            return $estimatedCurrentStepNumber > 1 && !$flow->getFormData()->canHaveRegion();
                        },
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'confirmation',
            ),
        );
    }
```

The form definition is also quite simple and works without problems:

```
class SelectExaminationStep1Form extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
  {
    dump("buildForm");
        $builder
      ->add('id', HiddenType::class)
      ->add('discipline', EntityType::class, array(
              'class' => 'EngineeringBundle:Discipline',
              'choice_label' => 'disciplineName',
              'label' => 'engineering.discipline.label'
              )
           );
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'createEngineeringStep1';
    }

}
```

services.yml:

```
EngineeringBundle\Form\SelectExaminationFlow:
    parent: craue.form.flow
    autowire: false
    autoconfigure: false
    public: true

engineering.form_flow:
    alias: EngineeringBundle\Form\SelectExaminationFlow
    public: true
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("create", name="engineering_create")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    return $this->processFlow(new ExaminationDate(), $this->get('engineering.form_flow'));

}
```

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: Cannot add greetings to the post, seems not to be saved. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem, resolved it by adding a constructor to `vendor/craue/formflow-bundle/Form/FormFlow.php` with the following content:

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, DataManagerInterface $dataManager, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher) {
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    $this->dataManager = $dataManager;
    $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
}
```

Make sure to place it after all setter-methods. Problem seems to be related to a symfony update.

Comment: Hi Stuffy, I modified my requirements and therefore the problem is now obsolete but thanks nonetheless. I will accept the answer for all the others with the same problem.